# Problem with video in flash on fullscreen

Tags: flash, video, fullscreen

sorry for my bad english. I added video to my flash in right bottom corner. In normal screen all good, but in fulscreen stretching only video(on full screen), but not all contetnt.

[image][1] http://img2.pict.com/cb/d2/2b/1161169/0/320/problem.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the Fullscreen feature was introduced mostly for video so that's why it defaults to that.

You need to do a bit of setup first to make sure you get the content you want in fullscreen.

I'd advise you to first set the desired scale mode and align for the stage.

e.g.

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

then the important bit you need, the [fullScreenSourceRect](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#fullScreenSourceRect) property:

```
//assuming you want to display 800 x 600 of you swf in fullscreen Mode
stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(0,0,800,600);
```

Goodluck!

Comment: it should just work. Do you get any errors? Also, if you're the FLVPlayback Compoment, make sure you've got fullScreenTakeOver set to false. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#fullScreenTakeOver

Comment: George thanks! it works, love you )) need only fullScreenTakeOver, stage preferences doesn't matter.